# Custom font is visible in design time and is not visible at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I added ttf files to my project, at the "Fonts" folder. I ensured that BuildActions was set to "Resource" (and "Do not copy").  I added resource to App's resource dict, like this:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="SomeFont">pack://application:,,,/Fonts/#SomeFont</FontFamily>
```

And, as result, in WPF designer I do see that the font works. But it doesn't work, when I start my application, at runtime. The recommendation in Microsoft article to reference resource as "./resources/#SomeFont" doesn't work in both design- and runtime.

So, the question is - how to make it work at runtime?

Comment: The [MSDN library article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/packaging-fonts-with-applications#adding-fonts-as-resource-items) shows how you need to edit the *project file*.  When you say "I ensured that BuildActions..." then you probably did not do that.

Comment: Thank you. I payed more attention to the article and user proposed there style on reference ("./[folder]/#[font-name]"). And it worked!